# Insert many to many Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

Estou fazendo uma inserção de dados em um `form` onde contem dados de uma relação muitos para muitos (*many to many*), a minha dificuldade esta em inserir **na tabela pivô mais de um dado de referencia**, segue post abaixo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podemos ver, tenho os seguintes `array`:

- lista_fornecedor_selecionado
- lista_fornecedor_valor

Eles tem o `id` do `fornecedor` que relaciona com o `produto` e um valor para cada `fornecedor`, se fosse para inserir apenas o `id` de `referencia`, vi que é feito desta maneira, exemplo:

```
$insert = Product::create($data_form);
$providers = $insert->providers()->attach(1);
```

Gostaria de saber como enviar alem do `id`, o valor para esse `fornecedor`, segue abaixo como esta meu model e como exemplo os dados já no banco:

Model:

```
public function providers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Provider::class)
                ->withPivot(['value', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
}
```

Banco:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme orientações, refiz e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Meu novo trexo de código:

```
$value_providers = array();
foreach ($data_form['lista_fornecedor_valor'] as $key => $value) {
    $value_providers[] = number_format((float)$value, 2, '.', ',');
}

$providers = $insert->providers()->attach($data_form['lista_fornecedor_selecionado'], ['value' => $value_providers]);
```

me retorna este erro:

```
Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `product_provider` (`created_at`, `product_id`, `provider_id`, `updated_at`, `value`) values (2017-10-14 20:50:19, 5782, 1, 2017-10-14 20:50:19, 20.00), (2017-10-14 20:50:19, 5782, 6, 2017-10-14 20:50:19, 20.00))
```

Outro ponto é que no sql os 2 values estão comm o valor da possição 1 do array, e não sequencial:

exemplo:

```
$value_providers = ['20.00', '15.00']
```

Comment: Renan tem que gravar item a item, então faz um for e passe um a um

Comment: entendi, codei desta forma e deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Não deixe de aceitar como resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a sua dúvida é [inserir na relação Muitos para Muitos no `Laravel` seguindo a documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) fica:

```
$insert = Product::create($data_form);
if ($insert) // foi inserido.
{
    $providers = $insert->providers()->attach(1, ['value' => 9.75]);
}
```

ou seja, após informar o `id`, passe um array de informações adicionais para gravar nessa tabela muitos para muitos que possui campos adicionais.

<sup>**Observação:** os valores no exemplo minimo forma fixados pode utilizar as variáveis.</sup>

**Referencia:** [Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: colocarei mais dados na pergunta!!!